# Xcode 15 commit button not shown

Tags: xcode

I just update Xcode to version 15, when I try to commit my code the commit button not showing.

The image from WWDC23:

[image]

The image from my Xcode app:

[image]

Comment: How about from the Menu > Source Control > Commit ?

Comment: I already tried that, in Xcode 15: Menu > Integrate > Commit, it’s not worked.

Comment: I had the same problem. Resolved it by good ol delete and re-clone.

Answer (score 14):

Some wonderful person has posted this to the [Apple Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738420?answerId=767456022#767456022):

> HI Folks. If the commit is missing after upgrading to Sonoma or going
> Xcode 15. Simply go to Xcode/settings/. Click on source code and click
> on Git. enter your author name and email. That should work.

Thank you KDT234...

This was the problem for me. My name was missing, email was present. I added it - and either after forcing a view reload (close the Source Control view maybe?) or an outright Xcode restart, it fixed it. I was able to recreate the problem by *removing the same field* and my commit box vanished again.

Xcode bug... Version 15.0 (15A240d)

Comment: Great, it works like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

go to Xcode -> Settings -> Source Control-> Git enter name & email id .

[image]

Alternatively you can also stage changes by right clicking them in xcode . open terminal navigate to you project and type - git commit -m "you commit details"